# configuring setPage for mmenu

Tags: mmenu

How do you configure [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-events.html) to indicate the current page in the (m)menu? Is there just something to include on each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmenu will style the current page based on it's class. If you are using Wordpress for example the current page is given the class "current-menu-item". When you are loading mmenu you need to tell it what class you have given the current page (default is 'selected'):

```
jQuery("#menu-top").mmenu({
  //options
}, {
  //configuration
  classNames: {
        selected: "current-menu-item"
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to 'give a page a class.' I'm no using WP, but almost every page on my site has variables on it e.g. index.php?a=57&b=33&c=127

Comment: Hey Adam, sorry I was a bit unclear with my solution. In your menu the "current page" should be given a class in html that indicates that it's the current page. You can use Chrome dev tools to inspect your page's html: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. Other browsers have similar tools available.